# How to push new elements to a nested array of objects in JavaScript using spread syntax

Tags: javascript

I want to create object like this

```
var items = [{'2021-07-06':[{todo:'Hello'},{todo:'World'}]}]
```

Here the date should be dynamic so I tried to push value to it like this but this doesn't work

```
{...items, [CurrentDate] : {...[CurrentDate], todo:'I am here'}}
```

[CurrentDate] refers to the current date here which is '2021-07-06' and push new todo in array. Also if the date key not present then I want to add new Date eg if '2021-07-08' is not present then add to object and add new todo to it.

Comment: *items* is an array, but in the "like this" code it's spread to an object.  `{...[CurrentDate}}` is going to spread a string like '2021-07-06' to an object like `{"0": "2", "1": "0", "2": "2", "3": "1", "4": "-", ...}`, i.e. with property names from the indexes and values from the characters. Perhaps you mean to do `[{[CurrentDate] : [...items, {todo:'I am here'}]}]` or similar.

Comment: yes @RobG correct it is updating items array like this, any idea or solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to find the right element in *items* to update (e.g. using [*findIndex*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)), then access it by index. Then you can update that object using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

However, spread is an inefficient approach as it creates a duplicate object for no reason. Likely [*push*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is much more efficient (and semantic) as it just adds an element to the array.

The following also handles the case where *currentDate* doesn't exist in the *items* array.

```js
let items = [{'2021-07-06': [{todo: 'Hello'}, {todo: 'World'}]}];

function updateItems(items, key, newItem) {
  // Find the right object in items
  let idx = items.findIndex(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(key));

  // If not found, append a new object
  if (idx == -1) {
    items = [...items, {[key]: newItem}];

  // Otherwise, update existing object
  } else {
    items[idx] = {
      [key]: [...items[idx][key], newItem]
    };
  }
  // Unnecessary but handy
  return items;
}

// Update existing object
updateItems(items, '2021-07-06', {todo: 'new item'});
console.log('Update existing item\n' + JSON.stringify(items));

// Add new object
// If using spread, must keep new array returned by updateItems
items = updateItems(items, '2021-07-07', {todo: 'new key and item'});
console.log('Add new item\n' + JSON.stringify(items));
```

Spread also creates a shallow copy, whereas *push* doesn't affect any existing elements in the array and is less code to type.

Comment: thanks for the answer but can it create new sub object with the date if it is not present like '2021-07-08' is not present can it create '2021-07-08' : [{todo : 'here'}] like this object

Comment: Yes, just test the value of *idx* and if it's -1, then push a new object like `items.push({[currentDate]: [/* items objects */] })`.

Comment: thanks @RobG I will try it and will let you know

Comment: one object gets added but when I try to add another object on same or different date I get items.findIndex is not a function

Comment: @Aariana—just noticed that. It's because *spread* copies the array so the global *items* references the un–updated array. I needed to assign the returned array to *items*, see updated post. It all depends on whether you think *updateItems* should mutate the passed in array, or create a copy (noting that the copy still references the original array's elements).

Answer (score 0):

it is easy.

```js
var items = [
   {
      '2021-07-06':[
         {todo:'Hello1'},{todo:'World1'},
         {todo:'Hello2'},{todo:'World2'},
         {todo:'Hello3'},{todo:'World3'},
         {todo:'Hello4'},{todo:'World4'},
       ],
      '2021-07-07':[
         {todo:'Hello11'},{todo:'World11'},
         {todo:'Hello22'},{todo:'World22'},
         {todo:'Hello33'},{todo:'World33'},
         {todo:'Hello44'},{todo:'World44'},
       ]
    }
];
```

let's imagine we want to add

```js
'2021-07-08':[
         {todo:'Hello111'},{todo:'World111'},
         {todo:'Hello222'},{todo:'World222'},
         {todo:'Hello333'},{todo:'World333'},
         {todo:'Hello444'},{todo:'World444'},
       ]
```

the way we would do so is like this

```js
 const newItem = '2021-07-08':[
         {todo:'Hello111'},{todo:'World111'},
         {todo:'Hello222'},{todo:'World222'},
         {todo:'Hello333'},{todo:'World333'},
         {todo:'Hello444'},{todo:'World444'},
       ];

const newTodo = {todo:"Hello5"};
///....

items = [...items, newItem];

/**
* IF YOU WANT TO ADD AN OBJ TO A DATE, DO IT LIKE THIS
*/

items[0]=[...items[0], newTodo];
```

items is an array, so you need to loop'em items to find the correct index

```js
for (let i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
  // before doing the next step validate if the items at position i is equals to an array
  
   const currentItem = [...items[i]];

  if (currentItem.anythingYouThinkWouldBeCondition === true) {
     currentItem.push(newTodo);
    items = [...items,currentItem];

   break;

  }


}
```