# Javascript spread on array index to 'push' new item to nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread

Consider the following data:

```js
let data = [
    { foo: true, bar: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
    { foo: true, bar: [ 8, 9,   ] }
];
```

I'm trying to `push` something to the nested `bar` array on index `1` using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`).

So the final array should become:

```js
[
    { foo: true, bar: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
    { foo: true, bar: [ 8, 9, 'new-item'  ] }
]
```

Normally, we'll just use push: `data[1].bar.push(0)`, but I need a spread solution

---

I've tried to use this approach:
[How to push new elements to a nested array of objects in JavaScript using spread syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68264140/how-to-push-new-elements-to-a-nested-array-of-objects-in-javascript-using-spread)

```
data = [ ...data, {[1]: { ...data[1], bar: [ ...data[1].bar, 'new-item' ] } }]
```

But this will append another object with a single key `1`, it does not alter `data[1]`.

---

Then, I've tried to use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) but again ended up with a new index:
[Replace array entry with spread syntax in one line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673783/replace-array-entry-with-spread-syntax-in-one-line-of-code)

```
data = [ ...data, Object.assign({}, data[1], { bar }})
```

---

**tl;dr**, How do I append something to an array, part of an object, that's inside an array of objects, *using the spread syntax*?

Please link me to a duplicate, or provide a way to do this

---

Playground:

```js
let data = [
    { foo: true, bar: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
    { foo: true, bar: [ 8, 9 ] }
];

// 'Regular' push method
// data[1].bar.push(0);

// Using spread reassign
// data = [ ...data, {[1]: { ...data[1], bar: [ ...data[1].bar, 'new-item' ] } }] 

// Using Object.assign
data = [ ...data, Object.assign({}, data[1], {bar: [ 'new-item' ] } ) ];

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Im not posting an answer, but that seems to work : `data = [ data[0], { ...data[1], bar: [ ...data[1].bar, 'new-item' ] } ]`

Comment: This works fine @Foobar, but how would you re-write this if `data` has 100 items and you need to change index 42?

Comment: @0stone0 @Foobar's answer is close to my answer: simply replace the static `....data[1]` with a `...data.slice(0, desired_index_to_edit)` (& follow with a `...data.slice(desired_index_to_edit+1)`)

Comment: May you work only on one item, and dont spread everthing: `data[1] = { ...data[1], bar: [ ...data[1].bar, 'new-item' ] } `  So `1` can now easy be `42`.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an outer `Object.assign` with an array as target and an object with the index as key.

```js
let
    data = [
        { foo: true, bar: [1, 2, 3] },
        { foo: true, bar: [8, 9] }
    ];

data = Object.assign(
    [...data],                            // target array
    { 1: {                                // array index as key
        ...data[1],
        bar: [...data[1].bar, 'new-item']
    } }
);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I wonder. why `[...data]` and not just `data`?

Comment: @Foobar, you could do that, but i would avoid to mutate the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) on the array itself.

```js
let data = [
    { foo: true, bar: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
    { foo: true, bar: [ 8, 9,   ] }
];
data = Object.assign([...data], {1: { ...data[1], bar: [...data[1].bar, 'new-item']}});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, +1. I'm sorry that Nina was 42 seconds faster. Will accept her answer if there are no shorter alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is more readable than many other options open to you but this satisfies the requirement of "using object spread".

```js
let data = [
  { foo: true, bar: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
  { foo: true, bar: [ 8, 9,   ] },
  { foo: false, bar: [ ] }
];

let idx = 1;
let newData = [ 
  ...data.slice(0, idx), 
  { 
    ...data[idx], 
    bar: [ ...data[idx].bar, 'new-item' ]
  },
  ...data.slice(idx+1)
];

console.log(newData);
```

This will first take your data and cut the array up to the item you wish to replace (index 1). A new object follows, then the rest of the array (if any) follows.

Comment: Thanks, this is decent, but dont really like the 2 slice. The object assign seems like a more clean way of doing this.

Comment: Unless my benchmark is wrong, slicing twice like this is faster than the `Object.assign()`, though.

Answer (score 0):

First, treat the array like an object with numbered keys, and use the spread operator and override the necessary index. Then, use Object.values() to treat it like an array.

```js
let data = [
  { foo: true, bar: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
  { foo: true, bar: [ 8, 9, ] }
]

data = Object.values({ ...data, 1: { ...data[1], bar: [ ...data[1].bar, 'new-item' ] } })

console.log(data)
```

In this particular case, if the index you need to alter is near the beginning of the array, you can also use an IIFE to allow for a destructuring approach, like this:

```js
let data = [
  { foo: true, bar: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
  { foo: true, bar: [ 8, 9, ] }
]

data = (([first, {bar, ...rest}]) => [first, {...rest, bar:[...bar, 'new-item']}])(data)

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the first element index to the modified element that uses `Array#map` and the spread operator as follows:

```js
const data = [
    { foo: true, bar: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
    { foo: true, bar: [ 8, 9,   ] }
];

data[1] = [data[1]].map(({foo,bar}) => ({foo,bar:[...bar,"some new value"]}))[0];

console.log( data );
```